# R Programming - throwing dice algorithm

Tags: r

I'd like to run a program in R that asks the user to pick a number of die, the run a simulation on the dice and determine the probability of rolling the minimum number to the maximum number.

For example, if the user picks 5 die, then the minimum roll would be 5x1=5 and the maximum roll would be 5x6=30.  I already have code for a set number of dice and a set total - just need to know how to augment it. 'd' is number of die, 'k' is the total of the roll, and 'nreps' is simulated runs (1,000,000 for example).  I'd like to store each probability in a vector and then give a plot (poisson distribution) of prob vs. total of roll (from min to max).

```
probtotk <- function(d, k, nreps){
  count <- 0
  #do the experiment nreps times
  for (rep in 1:nreps){
    total <- sum(sample(1:6, d, replace = TRUE))
  if (total == k) count <- count +1
}
 return(count/nreps) 
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by your goals. You seem to want to focus on a specific total (`k`), but also to want to look at each possible total (*"give a plot of prob vs. total of roll (from min to max)"*). Seems like you should just pick one of those two options (and the min to max seems more interesting and just as easy).

Comment: I mean, if you are rolling 5 dice, it doesn't make sense to do 1M simulations to find the prob that the total is 5, then 1M simulations to find the prob that the total is 6, ... 30. Rather, just do 1M simulations and look at the distribution of the totals.

Answer (score 3):

We can use R's vectorization to do this very quickly. As my comments suggest, I will not use `k`.

For `d` dice and `nreps` simulation, we will have `d * nreps` total die rolls. We simulate these all at once with `sample(6, size = d * nreps, replace = T)`. We put the results in a matrix with `nreps` columns and `d` rows, so each column represents a roll of `d` dice. The column sums give the totals for each roll. The `table` function counts the occurrence of each total, and the `prop.table` function turns it into a proportion.

```
dice_tot_prob = function(d, nreps) {
    rolls = matrix(sample(6, size = d * nreps, replace = T), ncol = nreps)
    totals = colSums(rolls)
    return(prop.table(table(totals)))
}

dice_tot_prob(5, 1e5)
totals
      5       6       7       8       9      10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23 
0.00015 0.00066 0.00200 0.00446 0.00904 0.01615 0.02655 0.03958 0.05456 0.07013 0.08379 0.09511 0.10065 0.10068 0.09214 0.08391 0.06936 0.05384 0.03891 
     24      25      26      27      28      29      30 
0.02576 0.01664 0.00880 0.00474 0.00180 0.00044 0.00015
```

The `prop.table` result is nice because it has a default plotting method:

```
plot(dice_tot_prob(5, 1e5))
```

[image]

Comment: Same solution but much better explanation :-)

Comment: Hey Gregor... I'm just a couple of days into R.  That is freakin' cool!  Can I say 'freakin' here?  Thanks!

Comment: Typed out your code, but it cannot find function "prob.table".  Do I need to download a package?

Comment: Copy/paste is safer than typing. It's `prop.table` with a `p` as in *proportion*.

Comment: Typed it to get a feel of how all this stuff is written.  Made the fix and it works.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
library(magrittr)
sample(1:6, nreps * d, replace = TRUE) %>%
  matrix(nrow = d) %>%
  colSums() %>%
  table() %>%
  divide_by(nreps)
```