# adding elements to a vector in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that simulate dolling m dice, n times, calculate the minimum of the outcome of the dice in each roll and then calculate the mean of the minimum and store the values into a vector.

```
mindice = function(n = 10, m = 3)
{
   v <- vector
   for(i in 1:10)
   {
      minima= numeric(n)
      for(i in 1:n)
      {
          minima[i] = min(sample(6,m,replace=T))
      }
      v[i] = mean(minima)
   }
v
}
```

I'm calling the function like that: mindice()
and the output is: Error in v[i] <- mean(minima) : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try `v <- vector()`. The use of `()` invokes the function. Providing the function name alone makes `v` a copy of the function itself.

Comment: I think you probably want `for (i in 1:n)`, not `1:10`.

Comment: Also, I just want to clarify: your code seems to be calculating the cumulative mean of the minima - is that what you want? Or do you just want to overall mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866523/r-programming-throwing-dice-algorithm?rq=1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fits your expectations. This function returns both the vector for the minimum per roll and their average

```
mindice <- function(n = 10, m = 3)
  {
  minima <- vector("numeric")
  for(i in 1:n){
  minima = c(minima, min(sample(6,m,replace=T)))
  }
  list(minimum_values=minima,
       mean_minima=mean(minima))
  }
mindice()
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment about using `v = vector()` rather than `v = vector` should solve the bug in the way you've written the function. If you're interested in a more R-like way to do this function, try this:

```
mindice2 = function(n = 10, m = 3) {
  rolls = sample(6, size = m * n, replace = TRUE)
  rolls = matrix(rolls, nrow = m)
  minima = apply(rolls, MARGIN = 2, FUN = min)
  cum_mean = cumsum(minima) / seq_along(minima)
  return(cum_mean)
}
```

Rather than sampling each roll separately, we do all the rolls at once (more efficient), and then put them in a matrix where each column is a roll of `m` dice. We can then use `apply` to find the minima, and `cumsum` to calculate the mean minimum after each roll.